# Chrome debugger shows undefined but there really is a value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

If you look at the picture, you will see a bunch of variables in the Scope on the right that are undefined.  Even when I hover around the "page" variable, it says undefined.  But then to the right of it, you also see:

```
page = Object {controlNode: Object, id: 149... etc etc}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?  Thank you

[image]

Comment: You can submit a bug report on https://crbug.com. Apparently it hasn't yet been implemented like some other use cases for let/const, for example https://crbug.com/681333

Answer (score 2):

You can open console by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Then type `page` in console. If it really has value, the value will be shown in console window.

If not work, try to add `page` to *Watch* list, which is in right panel of Chrome debugger.

Comment: i just tried and it says undefined.  ty for your input

Comment: Why would it show up if it's not in the global scope?

Comment: @user1189352 Are you in debugging mode when try this, and your breakpoint hit the line as picture in your question?

Comment: @MartinZhai yes sir i just tried.  i still get undefined

Comment: @E.Sundin Global objects' value can be checked in this way, sure. If you are in debug mode, this way also shows local objects' value in the scope of your breakpoint.

Comment: @user1189352 Please try my second solution, see if it works?

Comment: @user1189352 I noticed in your picture, there is two `page` in *Scope* list (in the right panel of debugger). One is undefined, one has value. There should be something wrong with it.

Comment: @MartinZhai it still says undefined.  maybe it really is a bug?  i've ran into this several times already on this specific project..

Comment: @MartinZhai what does that mean if there is 2 "page" objects?  is that something I am doing?  or is that the debugger bug?

Comment: I see you are using `page` before the `if...else...`statement, where is that `page` defined? Seems you have more than one `page` definition.

Comment: @MartinZhai it's only defined within the if...else.. statement.  i did change "let page" to "let page2" just to see what happens in the "else" statement and I can see the object now.  it is weird though that i still see "page" as undefined even though it shouldn't of hit the "if" statement and only the "else"